# Drawing a line using GL.LINES with Unity3d

Tags: c#, opengl, unity-game-engine

```
for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
{
    Debug.DrawLine(mapping[x].first, mapping[x].second);
}
Debug.DrawLine(_currentNode.Position, movement);
```

A few notes :
`mapping` is a dictionary with a tuple of `Vector3` coordinates.
the `for` loop is used to render the lines from the coordinates already visited and `_currentNode` is the position from which the current line gets drawn and it gets drawn to `movement` where `movement` is a `Vector3` which gets displaced over time.

What I would like to accomplish in my game is the following : I want to draw lines that are getting drawn with this method but these are only available in debug build.

For a few days I have been trying to draw a line with GL.LINES . I can't see any line drawn on my screen. I can't use LineRenderer. Where am I doing it wrong? The line gets shown with the Debug.DrawLine but its only on my debug build and not in my game. The line which GL.Begin() should generate isn't showing.

It's a 2D game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the question answered in GameDevelopment SE . Here's a link to a great answer : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96964/how-to-correctly-draw-a-line-in-unity

Basically the mistake I was making is I was trying to use GL.LINES outside of PostRender event.